# schema.ini not works as expected

Tags: sql-server

I am on a SQL Server 2012 enterprise hosted on a Windows Server 2012.
Something weird when I am trying to import data from a txt file.

The content in the txt file:

```
9.999.999,99|Account
```

The query used:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Text;Database=C:\;HDR=NO',
'SELECT * FROM TEST.TXT') txtTbl;
```

The schema.ini

```
[test.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=FALSE
DateTimeFormat=dd-MM-yyyy
CurrencyDecimalSymbol=,
CurrencyThousandSymbol=.

Col1  = Col1  currency
Col2  = Col2  Text Width 50
```

What drives me mad is the coll in the query result, no mater what kinds of proper datatype(currency,double,float) except text, the first column returns null. see below result.

```
col1 col2
NULL Account
```

When I was trying to play with Integer/Long datatype, it just returns 1 as below.

```
col1 col2
  1  Account
```

So it seems the setting CurrencyDecimalSymbol=,CurrencyThousandSymbol=. don't take effect. Is this some bug or do I miss something? Kindly shed me some light.